# Not been able to process simple form in Django?

Tags: python, django, forms

I am having problem with with a simple form POST. Here's my url.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', 'fileupload.views.show_template'), 
    url(r'^upload_file/', 'fileupload.views.upload_file'),
)
```

Here's my form.html:

```
form action="/upload_file/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Session</legend>
                <label for="input-one" class="float"><strong>Session Name:</strong></label><br />
                <input class="inp-text" name="input-one-name" id="session" type="text" size="30" /><br />

                <label for="input-two" class="float"><strong>Source:</strong></label><br />
                <input class="inp-text" name="input-two-name"  id="source" type="text" size="30" />

                <label for="input-two" class="float"><strong>Destination:</strong></label><br />
                <input class="inp-text" name="input-two-name"  id="destination" type="text" size="30" />
        </fieldset>



        <p><input class="submit-button" type="submit" alt="SUBMIT" name="Submit" value="Save" /></p>
        <p><input class="cancel-button" type="reset"  name="Save" value="Cancel" /></p>
    </form>
```

Here's my views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from fileupload.forms import UploadFileForm
from django.template import RequestContext


def show_template(request):
    return render_to_response('form.html', {'form': 'form'},  context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            sessiong = form.cleaned_data['session']
            sourceg = form.cleaned_data['source']
            destinationg = form.cleaned_data['destination']
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') 
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render_to_response('form.html', {'form': form},  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The problem is whenever I fill up the form and hit Save the form is not processed at all which clearly means my view upload_file is not working at all. What might be the problem? The simple logic is: user fills up the form, click save and the data's are stored in python variable which later I plan to store in a database.

Comment: You are missing a condition to check if the form is invalid.  Put an `else` for the `if form.is_valid()` check.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid no, there's no need to do that. The code follows the correct pattern: if the form is invalid, it'll fall through to the last line and show the form with errors.

Comment: What does 'form is not processed at all' mean?

Comment: @alexvassel: Yes I have created the model.  I am not redirected to the thanks page. After hitting the button save all I get is empty form and URL changes to http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload_file/. I'd to redirected to thanks page if it has worked, right?

Comment: i have a question for you: everything seems fine, except you didn't mark your form's encryption. are you uploading a file too? if so, you should add **enctype="multipart/form-data"** to your form attributes

Comment: For now I am not uploading files. I will include enctype once I add file uploading feature. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @user1755133: can you provide the definition of `UploadFileForm`? I suspect that the problem lies in the mismatch between the names of the attributes defined in `UploadFileForm` and the `name` attribute of the corresponding input elements.

Answer (score 1):

It's not processing because you don't tell it to do anything.  Change your view to look something like

```
def upload_file(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        sessiong = form.cleaned_data['session']
        sourceg = form.cleaned_data['source']
        destinationg = form.cleaned_data['destination']
        o = Object(foo=sessiong, bar=sourceg) # This, or whatever you want to *do* with this data
        o.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') 
else:
    form = UploadFileForm()
return render_to_response('form.html', {'form': form},  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

As things stand, your view just stores data to some variables and then spits out a redirect.

**Edit** - 
Also, check out the documentation on uploading files: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/?from=olddocs).  It would also be a good idea next time to include your UploadFileForm code.

Comment: What's the significance of this line? o = Object(foo=sessiong, bar=sourceg) I am getting error in Object as undefined variable.

Comment: that's an example.  In that case, I was just using it to represent the creation of a fictional model called "Object".  The point is that after you grab all your cleaned variables from the form, you have to actually do something with them.  You could create a model, or handle a file upload, or whatever you need to do.

Comment: Let's say if the form processed is successful, the data are stored in sessiong, sourceg, destinationg respectively. How do I know if the form processing is successful or not? I am not redirected to thanks page.

Comment: when you say it's not processed, is it returning the same form with the data filled in?  Because that would mean that you are re-rendering the same form.  Most likely form.is_valid() is returning false.

Comment: No, fresh form is returned with URL changed to http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload_file/ as I have mentioned that in form action. Also, I tried changing the else statement. No luck. The form didn't reach to the upload_file view.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the form data in database you need to create a model for it in your case
example

### models.py:

```
 from django.db import models
 class Upload(models.Model):
 session = models.CharField(max_length=200)
 Source = models.CharField(max_length=200)
 Destination = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

### views.py:

```
 def def upload_file(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
         session = request.POST.get('input-one-name')
         source = request.POST.get('input-two-name')
         destination = request.POST.get('input-three-name') #edit in your html page
         object = Upload() # this will create a object for your model
         object.Session = session
         object.Source = source
         object.Destination = destination
         object.save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') 
    else:
        return render_to_response('form.html', {'form': form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

this should save the form information in database

Comment: Thanks for the answer. TO get value using POST we use their id not their name. I will check this and let you know.